# How to save messages in the in-app messenger after session closes in Unity app

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a new messaging app. It is working fine. I want to make sure that the users see the messages they have sent every time they come back to use the app(Just like whatsapp and messenger, they have the chat history). I am working in Unity and C#. I do not know how to go about this problem.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately this question is far to broad for this community ... there are plenty of ways to go here ... store it offline device based e.g. in a json file ... or like the services you named store them online in a database device independend using a user login and a central server ... Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Its called "serialization"